# Appending elements to a list in python iteratively

Tags: python

I have a list a

```
a=[['a',1],['b',2],['c',3],['d',4],['e',5],['f',6]]
```

and would like to create a new list `c=[['a',1],['b',2],['e',5],['f',6]]`

I tried

```
    >>> e=[]
    >>> e.append(a[:2])
    >>> e.append(a[4:])
    >>> e
[[['a', 1], ['b', 2]], [['e', 5], ['f', 6]]]
```

But it gives me a list of lists

Please note that this is just a test case . I will be adding elements to the new list 'e' iteratively

Comment: Use 4 spaces indentation for code blocks, for further information see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Answer (score 2):

Using `append` you are adding new lists created with `a[:2]` and `a[4:]` when what you want to do is `extend` the list.

```
>>> a=[['a',1],['b',2],['c',3],['d',4],['e',5],['f',6]]
>>> e = []
>>> e.extend(a[:2])
>>> e.extend(a[4:])
>>> e
[['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['e', 5], ['f', 6]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply do a list concatenation .

```
>>> a=[['a',1],['b',2],['c',3],['d',4],['e',5],['f',6]]
>>> e = a[:2] + a[4:]
>>> e
[['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['e', 5], ['f', 6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

`a[:2]` will give you a list of the elements with index up to 2. Thus `e.append(a[:2])` will append the following list `[['a', 1], ['b', 2]]` as the first element.

You can use:

```
e.append(a[0])
e.append(a[1])
[...]
```

But if this is the best solution is questionable. The best solution would depend on your context.

Answer (score 0):

```
a=[['a',1],['b',2],['c',3],['d',4],['e',5],['f',6]]
e = list(a)
e.remove(e[3])
e.remove(e[2])
print e
```

[['a',1],['b',2],['e',5],['f',6]]

You can remove any subsequence you want.